# solve $|\sin(a)|=\cos(3a)$

Tags: trigonometry, systems-of-equations

$|\sin(a)|=\cos(3a)$ is an alternative version of an equation $\sqrt{1-x^2}=4x^3-3x$, where I made a substitution $x=\cos(a)$ for $x \in [-1, 1]$. Unfortunately, I have no idea how to solve trigonometric equations.

Comment: Why not work with the original equation then? $1-x^2 = x^2(4x^2-3)^2$ seems doable?

Comment: of course it is, but the essence (at least given by the problem set name) of the equation is to solve it with trig substitutions.

Comment: Why would you do it if it makes the problem harder instead?

Comment: To teach myself trig substitution trick in practice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider

Case 1:  $0 \le a \le \frac \pi 6$ then $0 \le 3a \le \frac \pi 2$.  Than $\sin a \ge 0$ and $\cos 3a \ge 0$.

Then $a$ and $3a$ are both in the first quandrant.  And the identity that will apply is $\sin a = \cos (\frac \pi 2 - a)$.

So we must have $\frac\pi 2 - a= 3a$ or $a =\frac {\pi} 8$.

Case 2:  $\frac \pi 6 < a < \frac \pi 2$.  Then $\frac \pi 2 < 3a < \frac {3\pi}2$.  But then $\cos 3a < 0$ and that's not the case.

Case 3: $\frac \pi 2 \le a \le \frac {2\pi}3$.  And $\frac {3\pi}2 \le 3a \le 2\pi$.  Then $\sin a \ge 0$ and $\cos 3a \ge 0$.

Now $a$ is in the second quadrant and $a$ is in the fourth and the indentity that is relevent is.

$\sin (\frac \pi 2 + \alpha) = \cos (2\pi - \alpha)$.

So $a = \frac \pi 2 + \alpha$ and $3a = 2\pi - \alpha$ so $a+ 3a = 2\pi + \frac \pi 2$ so $4a = \frac {5\pi }2$ and $a = \frac {5\pi} 8$.

Case 4: $\frac {2\pi}3 < a \le  \frac {5\pi}6$ and $2\pi < 3a \le 2\pi + \frac {\pi}2$.

Then $a$ is in second quadrant but $3a$ is in the first but over $2\pi$.

The identity that applies here is $\cos (2\pi + \alpha) = \sin (\frac \pi 2 + \alpha)$.

So $a = \frac \pi 2 + \alpha$ and $3a = 2\pi + \alpha$ ans so $3a - a = \frac {3\pi }2$ and $a= \frac {3\pi}4$.

Case 5: $\frac {5\pi}6 < a < \frac {7\pi}6$ and $\frac {5\pi}2 < 3a < \frac {7\pi}2$.  But then $\cos 3a < 0$ which isn't possible.

Case 6: $\frac {7\pi}6 \le a \le \frac {4\pi}3$ so $\frac {7\pi}2 \le 3a \le 4\pi$ then $\sin a \le 0$ but $\cos 3a = -\sin a \ge 0$.

The identity here is $-\sin (\pi + \alpha) = \sin (\pi - \alpha)=\cos(\frac {7\pi}2 + \alpha)$.

So $a = \pi + \alpha$ and $3a = \frac {7\pi}2 + \alpha $ so $2a = \frac {5\pi}2$ and $a =\frac {5\pi}4$.

Case 7: $\frac {4\pi}3 \le a \le \frac {3\pi}2$ so $4\pi \le 3a \le \frac {9\pi}2$.

Then identity to use here is $-\sin (\frac {3\pi} 2 - \alpha)= \cos (4\pi + \alpha)$

So $a = \frac {3\pi}2  -\alpha$ and $3a =4\pi +\alpha$ so $4a = 4\pi + \frac {3\pi}2$ so $a =\pi +\frac {3\pi}8 = \frac {11\pi}8$.

Case 8: $\frac {3\pi}2 < a < \frac {11\pi } 6$ so $\frac {9\pi}2< 3a < \frac {11\pi}2$ so $\cos 3a < 0$.

And final final case

9:  $\frac {11\pi}6 \le a < 2\pi$ then $\frac {11\pi}2 \le 3a < 6\pi$.

The identity we need is $-\sin (\frac {3\pi}2 + \alpha) = \cos(6\pi - \alpha)$.

So $a + 3a = 6\pi + \frac {3\pi }2$ and so $a = \frac {15\pi}8$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

$$\sin(a)=\cos(\pi/2-a)$$
and
$$\cos(A)-\cos(B)=-2\sin\left(\frac{A-B}{2}\right)\sin\left(\frac{A+B}{2}\right)$$
$$\cos(A)+\cos(B)=2\cos\left(\frac{A-B}{2}\right)\cos\left(\frac{A+B}{2}\right)$$

Answer (score 1):

*Hint:*

One possibility is $$\sin a=\cos 3a \implies \cos(\frac{\pi}{2} - a) =\cos 3a$$ and the other is $$-\sin a = \cos 3a \implies \cos(\frac{\pi}{2} +a ) =\cos 3 a$$

Now, $$\cos x=\cos y \iff x\pm y = 2k\pi$$ Find all possibilities for $a$, and hence $x=\cos a$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

$1-x^2=x^2(3-4x^2)^2\iff -16x^6+24x^4-10x^2+1=0$

If we set $w=x^2$ we get $-16w^3+24w^2-10w+1=0$ which has $\frac{1}{2}$ as a solution

Comment: $x=\frac12$ is not a solution pre-squaring..

Comment: @Henno Brandsma Right,but I just mentioned it to show how to decrease the degree of the last equation.